# How to make restful like urls

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, restful-url

Presently I got a url that is passed as such `domain.tld/pages.php/parameter` then the `pages.php` script simply looks at the `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URL"]` to make the necessary changes to the page.

I have looked up a number of explanations about how to remove the `.php` from the url, however all of them break the `/parameter` portion of the url and the page simply won't load. If I look up the closest facsimile it is "restful" urls, but they pass the parameters to another script like `index.php` or `api.php` which is not my goal. I have `otherpage.php` that should work all the same.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: What is your current .htaccess?

Comment: Pretty much what Sultan Shindi suggested.

Comment: Did you check PHP-FPM or Apache's log for detail logs of the "internal error" it mentioned? What does the error log say when you visit the URL and get the error page?

Comment: @KoalaYeung This is the logs error:

```Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.```

Comment: The rewrite rules doesn't seem to trigger any redirection. There must be some other coding or configurations that caused the redirection loop. Please check your .htaccess and PHP coding.

Comment: .htacess is exactly what Sultan Shindi provided and I even removed all the php script and just left the html. If I go to ```domain.tld/page.php``` it is fine, ```domain.tld/page``` fine, ```domain.tld/page/``` fails with that error ```domain.tld/page/parameter``` fails with that error.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use rewrite rules on `.htaccess` to change the urls' direction and rules (in case of Apache webserver).

1. Firstly create a `.htaccess` file on the base website directory where your index.php or whatever files lies.
2. Then, write the below code on the created `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

3. Visit any file of your website without writing `.php` extension, for example: if you have a file called `otherpage.php` and the previous working url path to it was `https://domain.tld/otherpage.php` then now you could visit the same page with this url `https://domain.tld/otherpage`.

Comment: This is the same answer I see everywhere. However if I attempt to visit for example ```domain.tld/pages/``` I get ```Internal Server Error```. If I try ```domain.tld/pages/parameter``` I get the same error. So this is not the solution.